# Apache: Returns broken file if requested during file copy

Tags: php, linux, apache, file-io, filesystems

On my webserver I generate an animated gif every 15 minutes. The result gets written into a temporary directory, then I copy the gif (some MBs) into the htdocs directory via php:copy(). However, if there's an http request for the file during the copy process, Apache will return only a portion of the file, which results in a broken animation.

How can I solve this? Using rename() instead of copy()? Or is there a way to instruct Apache to wait for filesystem operations before delivering a file (shouldn't this be default anyway?)?

Answer (score 0):

Definitely use rename instead of copy.  Rename (mv, essentially), just changes file pointers around, so even if it's not *truly* atomic (I haven't been able to find a conclusive source, but I suspect it is) it'll be so fast that the chances of someone loading a page in that interval is virtually zero.

For more info, see:

- [MV vs. RM](https://superuser.com/questions/101676/is-there-some-difference-between-mv-and-cp-rm-the-old-file-on-unix)
- [This comment](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php#60341) from the PHP manual

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy into a temporary filename and then rename the temporary.  Then the server will never see an incomplete file.